# CSS 3D effect banner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to illustrate a banner that goes behind the body and continues in the background.

I want to achieve something like this:
[image]

But the difficult part is the wrap-around when it goes to the background (3D-effect).

This is what I got so far: https://jsfiddle.net/4v6xLtyf/

```
<body>
  <div class="navbar background-banner">
  </div>
  <div class="body-content">
    <div style="height:1000px" class="container content-block">
      <h1 style="text-align: center">My Website</h1>

      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-top navbar-custom-top">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a>Home</a></li>
            <li><a>About Us</a></li>
            <li><a>Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Nice idea. You probably have to creat those triangle parts by yourself, with `skewX()` and the Position relativ to the content-block.

Comment: Do you have CSS you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with `:before`, `:after` and `border` to do the trick, something close to what you need could be adding the following CSS rules:

```
.navbar-custom-top:before {
    content: "";
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-top: 31px solid #bb5911;
    top: 50px;
    left:0;
}
.navbar-custom-top:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-top: 31px solid #bb5911;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0;
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4v6xLtyf/1/)

Then play with the size, position and colors to match exactly what you need.

Comment: Can you explain how this works and what it is doing?

Comment: I like the solution but an explanation as @Rob says would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Update answer......

I made an example from @user2570380 reference link.

Just take a look my [link_codpen](http://codepen.io/ashikjs/full/mORvwv/) .

**New CSS** with **two new class** `ribbonoutline` & `ribbonul`

```
/***********************/

.ribbonul:before, .ribbonul:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #BB5911 transparent transparent transparent;
 bottom: -1em;
}
.ribbonul:before {
 left:0;
 border-width: 1em 0 0 1em;
}
.ribbonul:after {
 right: 0;
 border-width: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
.ribbonoutline:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(234, 115, 29), rgb(255, 168, 0)) !important;
    height: 28px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -9999;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)) !important;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: Algerian;
}


/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */

.body-content {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  position:relative; 
  z-index:1
}


/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/

.dl-horizontal dt {
  white-space: normal;
}


/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */

input,
select,
textarea {
  max-width: 280px;
}

.content-block {
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 padding: 22px;
 width: 70%;
 margin: auto;
 height: 500px;
}

.background-banner {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(234, 115, 29), rgb(255, 168, 0)) !important;
  margin-top: 150px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-custom-top {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(234, 115, 29), rgb(255, 168, 0)) !important;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-right: -40px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.custom-container {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  border-top-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}

.navbar-header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.navbar-nav > li {
  display: inline;
}

ul.navbar-nav {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  min-height: 1000px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: black;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}


/***********************/
/***********************/
/***********************/

.ribbonul:before, .ribbonul:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #BB5911 transparent transparent transparent;
 bottom: -1em;
}
.ribbonul:before {
 left:0;
 border-width: 1em 0 0 1em;
}
.ribbonul:after {
 right: 0;
 border-width: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
.ribbonoutline:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(234, 115, 29), rgb(255, 168, 0)) !important;
    height: 28px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar background-banner">
  </div>
  <div class="body-content">
    <div class="container content-block">
      <h1 style="text-align: center">My Website</h1>

      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-top navbar-custom-top">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse ribbonoutline">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav ribbonul">
            <li><a>Home</a></li>
            <li><a>About Us</a></li>
            <li><a>Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
  
    </div>
 
  </div>
```